# Is it possible to perform conditions on a Firestore Timestamp?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query my Firestore Database for a list of Sales performed between two dates, that are entered by the user, however, I don't want to query the entire `Sale` collection and want to only obtain the documents that fall between the two entered dates. I stored the user's entered dates into a `Calendar` object through the following way:

```
Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault());
Calendar endDate = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

*I then created an `OnDateChangedListener` for each DatePicker (one for the start date and one for the end date) and placed the following line depending on which one was clicked*

`startDate/endDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, 0, 0, 0);`

The three zeros are for setting the hour, minutes and seconds respectively.

My question is, am I technically able to perform the following query?

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("Sales")
        .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Date", startDate)
        .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Date", endDate)
        .get()
```

I have been able to work my way around the other data types for Firestore, the Timestamp is the only one I am struggling to understand and get right. I highly appreciate any feedback.

**Edit**

I realised upon looking at the question again, that the field names for the database are both the same i.e. "Date" and not "StartDate" and "EndDate". I also placed an image below to showcase what my Sale collection with a single document will look like.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added a screenshot to showcase the database's structure. Thanks again for the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to query your "Sale" collection by the "Date" property, you have two options. You can either use a Firestore [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) object or a Java [Date](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date) object with a range filter. Passing a `Calendar` object to the .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo() and .whereLessThanOrEqualTo() methods, will always yield no results. To solve this problem, you should convert both `Calendar` objects:

```
Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault());
Calendar end = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

Into Date objects like this:

```
Date startDate = start.getTime();
Date endDate = end.getTime();
```

Not sure why this method is called [getTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) and not getDate(), however it returns the deseired [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object.

Now, the following query:

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("Sales")
        .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Date", startDate)
        .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Date", endDate)
        .get()
```

Will return all objects that exist between startDate and endDate.